# When two of the values have the same address

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main ()
{
  int firstvalue = 5, secondvalue = 15;
  int * p1, * p2;

  p1 = &firstvalue;  // p1 = address of firstvalue
  p2 = &secondvalue; // p2 = address of secondvalue
  *p1 = 10;          // value pointed by p1 = 10
  *p2 = *p1;         // value pointed by p2 = value pointed by p1
  p1 = p2;           // p1 = p2 (value of pointer is copied)
  *p1 = 20;          // value pointed by p1 = 20

  cout << "firstvalue is " << firstvalue << endl;
  cout << "secondvalue is " << secondvalue << endl;
  return 0;
}
```

The output is 10 20. Shouldn't the output be 20 20? What I am thinking is because it does p1 = p2 therefore both p1 and p2 have same address, and then it sets value pointed by p1 = 20. So their values suppose to change to 20.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the operation `p1 = p2;` you are changing pointer `p1`  but not the address of `firstvalue`. `p1` does not point to `firstvalue` anymore but points to `secondvalue`

Comment: Your answer makes perfect senses. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

```
  p1 = &firstvalue;
  p2 = &secondvalue;

  // here, p1 points to first, p2 points to second, first is 5, second is 15

  *p1 = 10;          

  // here, p1 points to first, p2 points to second, first is 10, second is 15

  *p2 = *p1; 

  // here, p1 points to first, p2 points to second, first is 10, second is 10

  p1 = p2;   

  // here, p1 points to second, p2 points to second, first is 10, second is 10

  *p1 = 20;  

  // here, p1 points to second, p2 points to second, first is 10, second is 20
```

Answer (score 2):

Let me rephrase your comments:

```
  p1 = &firstvalue;  // p1 points to firstvalue
  p2 = &secondvalue; // p2 points to secondvalue
  *p1 = 10;          // means firstvalue = 10
  *p2 = *p1;         // means secondvalue = firstvalue, which is 10
  p1 = p2;           // p1 now points to secondvalue and not to firstvalue any more
  *p1 = 20;          // means secondvalue = 20
```

net effect: firstvalue is 10, no pointer points to it. secondvalue is 20, both p1 and p2 point to it

Answer (score 1):

Let's do this line by line:

```
int firstvalue = 5, secondvalue = 15;
int * p1, * p2;

p1 = &firstvalue;  // p1 = address of firstvalue
p2 = &secondvalue; // p2 = address of secondvalue
```

Until here, `firstvalue = 5, secondvalue = 15`.

```
*p1 = 10;          // value pointed by p1 = 10
```

Now `*p1 = 10`, thus `firstvalue = 10, secondvalue = 15`.

```
*p2 = *p1;         // value pointed by p2 = value pointed by p1
```

Now `*p2 = secondvalue = *p1 = firstvalue = 10`, thus `firstvalue = 10, secondvalue = 10`.

```
p1 = p2;           // p1 = p2 (value of pointer is copied)
*p1 = 20;          // value pointed by p1 = 20
```

And now `*p1 = secondvalue = 20`, thus `firstvalue = 10, secondvalue = 20`.

Answer (score 0):

Firstvalue and secondvalue are not pointers, they are your variables, be careful!

The pointers are p1 and p2, so the output you are expected is for :

```
cout << "firstvalue is " << *p1 << endl;
cout << "secondvalue is " << *p2 << endl;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 first  second   first  second   first  second   first  second     first  second
 value  value    value  value    value  value    value  value      value  value
 +---+  +---+    +---+  +---+    +---+  +---+    +---+  +---+      +---+  +---+
 |   |  |   |    |   |  |   |    |   |  |   |    |   |  |   |      |   |  |   |
 | 5 |  | 15|    | 10|  | 15|    | 10|  | 10|    | 10|  | 15|      | 10|  | 20|
 +---+  +---+    +---+  +---+    +---+  +---+    +---+  +-^-+      +---+  +-^-+
   ^      ^        ^      ^        ^      ^        +------|          +------|
 +-|-+  +-|-+    +-|-+  +-|-+    +-|-+  +-|-+    +-|-+  +-+-+      +-|-+  +-+-+
 | | |  | | |    | | |  | | |    | | |  | | |    | + |  | | |      | + |  | | |
 | + |  | + |    | + |  | + |    | + |  | + |    |   |  | + |      |   |  | + |
 +---+  +---+    +---+  +---+    +---+  +---+    +---+  +---+      +---+  +---+
  p1     p2       p1     p2       p1     p2       p1     p2         p1     p2
```

As mentioned in other answers, You have two pointers pointing to the same variable now. Your `first value` is not altered by `*p1 = 20` because `p1` points to `second value`not `first value`